# Django admin prefetch related on property

Tags: django, django-admin, django-database

I have models `Merchant` and `PhoneNumber`. `PhoneNumber` has a foreign key to `Merchant`, and `Merchant` has property `business_phone_number` which fetches the first phone number in the set of the phone numbers. In Django admin, for the `Merchant` model, I have `business_phone_number` in `list_display`. Although I've put `prefetch_related(phonenumber_set)`, it still queries `PhoneNumber` 100 times. What am I doing wrong? Here's the simplified code:

```
class PhoneNumber(models.Model):
    ...
    merchant = models.ForeignKey("merchant.Merchant", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    ...
    
class Merchant(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    @property
    def business_phone_number(self):
        number = self.phonenumber_set.first()
        if number:
            return number.phone_number
        return None
```

and then in Django admin I have:

```
@admin.register(Merchant)
class MerchantAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("name", "business_phone_number", ...)
    ...
```

I've put in get_queryset:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    return super().get_queryset(request).prefetch_related("phonenumber_set")...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hit in db made `queryset.first()`.
For work with prefetched data you should use only `prefetched_something.all()`.
in your case:

```
@property
def business_phone_number(self):
    for number in self.phonenumber_set.all():
        return number
```

or you can use `next()`.

```
@property
def business_phone_number(self):
    return next((number for number in self.phonenumber_set.all()), None)
```

You can use `self.phonenumber_set.all().iterator()` instead of generator, but i have not use it with prefetch data.

Comment: Thank you so much! I also realized it now, and just came to write that I resolved the problem by redefining the function business_phone number    ```def business_phone_number(self): numbers = [n for n in self.phonenumber_set.all()] return numbers[0] if numbers else None```

Comment: [ something ] is a list. It works slowly. Try to use next and generator instead of